# How to deploy a React App to Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure

So I am trying to deploy a simple react app to Azure, I originally started out with something complex that I was trying to deploy. I was receiving a lot of error codes that weren't making sense, this is my first time trying to get something like this up on azure. So i decided to go back to the basics and try getting a the simplest form of a react app working on the app services. so i created a new react app from `npx create-react-app myapp` I created a new repository and uploaded that code into my github, went to azure, created a new app service, with the lowest possible tiered pricing, and connected my github to that app service to deploy. during the deploy though, i am getting this error stack

```
Run npm install

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /home/runner/work/react-basic/react-basic/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /home/runner/work/react-basic/react-basic/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.4 postinstall /home/runner/work/react-basic/react-basic/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1646 packages from 787 contributors and audited 1786 packages in 26.789s

65 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 781 vulnerabilities (100 low, 182 moderate, 499 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> hello@0.1.0 build /home/runner/work/react-basic/react-basic
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  39.38 KB  build/static/js/2.43f2ee7e.chunk.js
  770 B     build/static/js/runtime-main.d67d11c1.js
  284 B     build/static/js/main.2c72b389.chunk.js
  72 B      build/static/css/main.d498bfb3.chunk.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy


> hello@0.1.0 test /home/runner/work/react-basic/react-basic
> react-scripts test

No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /home/runner/work/react-basic/react-basic
  2 files checked.
  testMatch: /home/runner/work/react-basic/react-basic/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}, /home/runner/work/react-basic/react-basic/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx} - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 2 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello@0.1.0 test: `react-scripts test`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hello@0.1.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-09-10T15_42_53_869Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've looked over several pieces of documentation, but i just havent yet found anything that shows the correct way to setup a react app on azure, one such documentation got close, it had me download the publish profile from the app service and save it into the github secret keys and then setup a workflow from github actions, this example got me the closest, as the app would build, and deploy, except it wouldnt work, its like it wouldnt go into the build folder and target the index.html, and at the wwwroot on the kudu console. all files including the build folder were present.

at this point i just want the simplest way to deploy a SPA to azure app services. Any specific documentation would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

You can deploy the react app to Azure App Service using VS code.

Open your Project in VS Code.

Go to Extensions. Search for Azure App Service and click on Install.

[image]

Go to Azure App Service. Sign in to your Azure Account.

Click on Deploy to Web App.

Select your Subscription. Select your App Service.

Now you should be able to deploy your react app to Azure App Service

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Austin Howard - Please follow the above steps, let me know if you come across any issues.

Comment: I tried this once. It wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @Austin Howard - I have edited the Answer, you can try deploying you app using VS Code.

Comment: @HashithaVeeramalla-MT, I never got around to saying if this was the answer or not, mostly because i figured out a work around myself. in that i send the resources from the build folder to the client when the server `/` is hit. However, i have to ask, how does App Services know to serve the build folder here? this is, or was, my major roadblock, cause i needed to deploy a server and a client, and it looked as though the only way to serve the client was azures static web apps. and not the app services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! very helpful! Any idea on how to publish only the changed files? or at least a way to publish a single file overriding the current file on the target hosting server..